# Which white space in grep is the best standard?

Tags: regex, grep

I needed to find a word which is enclosed by white spaces in a file.

A file, test.txt

```
head target_word tail
```

Spaces between words above can be tab.
And I tried

```
grep -e '\starget_word\s' test.txt
```

It failed to find "target_word". But

```
grep -e "[[:space:]]target_word[[:space:]]" test.txt
```

and

```
grep -e "[ \t]target_word[ \t]" test.txt
```

are working well.

Which white space is the most acceptable one? Please let me know.

Comment: `\s` is PCRE, you need to use `-P` flag. `[[:space:]]` is posix, so is what may be considered the most acceptable as it is most portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match either a space or a tab, you can use `[[:blank:]]`. This is defined as either a space or a tab, regardless of the locale settings.

From [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html):

> In the POSIX locale, only the `<space>` and `<tab>` shall be included.
>
> In a locale definition file, the `<space>` and `<tab>` are automatically included in this class.

You can also use `[[:space:]]` but this contains other characters in addition to spaces and tabs.

Comment: @Tom Fenech : I did not know I can use [[:blank:]] in grep because I could not search word 'blank' in grep manual. In addition, your answer let me know the difference between them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match any kind of whitespace - depending on your locale - use [`[[:space:]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html). In the C locale it matches: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space. However, depending on your locale settings, it might match additional characters which are considered space in that locale.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to state `\t` and  (`<space>`), you can:

```
$ cat > target.txt
head target_word tail                         # space-separated
head    target_word     tail                  # tab-separated
$ grep $'[\t ]target' target.txt
head target_word tail
head    target_word     tail
```

**Edit**:

About the `\t` and `grep`:

```
$ cat > test
1 1        # space-delimited
2       2  # tab-delimited
$ grep \t test
$ grep '\t' test
$ grep "\t" test
$ grep $'\t' test
2       2
$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.16
# - -
```

Which `grep` are you using? Mine doesn't work with `\t`.

Comment: I take back what I said - looks like you need a literal tab character if you're not going to use a C-style string.

Answer (score 0):

You can even try `cat test.txt | grep " target_word "`.

```
                                 # ^space      ^space
```

Incidentally, you don't need the `cat`.
Much better to do `grep " target_word " test.txt`.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Varun M : Thank you Varun M. The space in test.txt can be tab. I did not express it. Sorry for it. And Thank you for simplify the example.

Comment: @123, I wanted to show that you can explicitly include a space in the grep search.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP wants to match a tab

Comment: @hek2mgl, ya he/she modified the question later. Oh well, sometimes simplicity is alright. I've used the space in the search multiple times. 
Helps if there are searches like `grep "  target_word   " input.txt`(uneven spaces around the word).

Comment: @hek2mgl. Yes, thank to instruction by Varun M. I modified example and added tab to match explicitly.